# IDs specified in Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, reflection, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am writing an eclipse plugin. For many of the components, it is necessary to specify an ID in order to reference them dynamically. Is there any gotcha in using the fully qualified class name of the component as its id?

In other words, is there any downside / mistake in specifying:

```
private static final String ID = MyComponent.class.getName();

public static String id() {
    return ID;
}
```

for my plugin components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, there is nothing wrong with using the fully qualified class name as an extension point ID. And for simplicity, I usually stick to this naming convention and haven't seen a drawback in practice either.

However, the Eclipse naming conventions for extension and extension point IDs are to use the ID of the plug-in as a qualifier, followed by a CamcelCase'd name. The name sometimes starts with an uppercase letter.

Most views, for example,  start with an uppercase letter, like the *Package Explorer* view: `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer`. The *debug context*, on the other hand is identified with `org.eclipse.debug.ui.debugging` .

If your plug-in provides API for others to build upon, the extensions are considered API, too. If you want to exclude an extension, put an `internal` segment after the plug-in part of the ID, for example:
`com.example.myplugin.internal.myView`.

Answer (score 1):

Most ids are used in extension points in plugin.xml files as well as in Java code so it is probably not a good idea to use a class name like this. You will still have to give the string value in the plugin.xml and using a different formulation in the Java files will make it more difficult to search all files for occurrences of the id.

Usually ids are made up of the plugin id + one extra word.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But would it not actually be easy to searchand replace during refactoring (for repackaging / renaming) given that the IDE can replace the fully qualified name in Java and non-Java files as well?